# How do I transform an array using Jolt?

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am getting a null value for my transformed object when trying to convert something like this:

```json
{   
  "employees": [
    { "f_name" : "tom", "l_name" : "smith" },
    { "f_name" : "don", "l_name" : "jones" }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```json
{
  "employees": [
    { "firstName" : "tom", "lastName" : "smith" },
    { "firstName" : "don", "lastName" : "jones" }
  ]
}
```

This is the spec I am using:

```json
[
  {
    "operation" : "shift",
    "spec" : {
      "employees" : {
        "f_name" : "firstName",
        "l_name" : "lastName"
      }
   }
 ]
```

This is the code I am using:

```
List<Object> chainrSpecJSON = JsonUtils.classpathToList("path/spec.json");
Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(chainrSpecJSON);
Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.classpathToObject("path/input.json");

Object transformed = chainr.transform(inputJSON);
System.out.println(transformed);
```

I was able to successfully transform the following input with the same spec and code as above:

```json
{   
  "employees": 
    { "firstName" : "tom", "lastName" : "smith" }
}
```

So what do I need to do to transform an array of employee objects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This spec does what you want

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employees": {
        "*": {
          "f_name": "employees[&1].firstName",
          "l_name": "employees[&1].lastName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The key thing is you need to use a **`"*"`** to loop thru all the elements of the **`employees`** array, then when you recurse / match down to **`f_name`** and **`l_name`**, you need to reference the index array using **`[&1]`**, which means look up the tree two levels, zero then one, and use that as an index array in the output.

Comment: is there a way to not specify "employees" in ``employees[&1]`` (like reusing the matching key)?

Comment: Yep    "f_name": "&2[&1].firstName"

Answer (score 0):

One option would be generating new keys by copying the existing ones through use of a **modify** transformation, and the get rid of the originals by using **remove** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "employees": {
        "*": {
          "firstName": "@1,f_name",
          "lastName": "@1,l_name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*_name": "" // common key identifier
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]