# Jolt Transform JSON Spec

Tags: java, jolt

I need to transform below Input JSON to output JSON and not sure about how to write spec for that. Need to re-position one field ("homePage") as a root element. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Input JSON :

```
[{
    "uuid": "cac40601-ffc9-4fd0-c5a1-772ac65f0587",
    "pageId": 123456,    
    "page": {
      "indexable": true,
      "rootLevel": false,
      "homePage": false      
    }
}]
```

Output JSON :

```
[{
    "uuid": "cac40601-ffc9-4fd0-c5a1-772ac65f0587",
    "pageId": 123456,
    "homePage": false,  
    "page": {
      "indexable": true,
      "rootLevel": false           
    }
}]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried 'remove', just removing. Tried 'shift', giving only one element. Not sure, how to combine both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Jolt Spec should work for you. Tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "uuid": "[&1].uuid",
        "pageId": "[&1].pageId",
        "page": {
          "indexable": "[&2].page.indexable",
          "rootLevel": "[&2].page.rootLevel",
          "homePage": "[&2].homePage"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

input:

```
{
  "uuid" : "cac40601-ffc9-4fd0-c5a1-772ac65f0587",
  "pageId" : 123456,
  "page" : {
    "indexable" : true,
    "rootLevel" : false
  },
  "homePage" : false
}
```

output:

```
[ {
  "uuid" : "cac40601-ffc9-4fd0-c5a1-772ac65f0587",
  "pageId" : 123456,
  "page" : {
    "indexable" : true,
    "rootLevel" : false
  },
  "homePage" : false
} ]
```

---

**Explanation:**

From the [javadoc](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java)

> `&` Path lookup
>
> As Shiftr processes data and walks down the spec, it maintains a data structure describing the path it has walked.
> The `&` wildcard can access data from that path in a 0 major, upward oriented way.
> Example:
>
> ```
> {
>    "foo" : {
>        "bar": {
>          "baz":  // &0 = baz, &1 = bar, &2 = foo
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

Next thing: How to wrap the output object into the array?
A good example can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865871/how-do-i-transform-an-array-using-jolt).

So, in our case:

- `"[&1].uuid"` says:

> Place the `uuid` value in the object inside the array. The index of the array is indicated by the `&1` wildcard. For `uuid` it will be the index of the array, where the object with `uuid` key is placed in the original json.

- Next, `[&2]` is similar to `[&1]`. However, looking at the `"indexable"` key, it is one level deeper in the input json. Thats why instead of `[&1]` we used `[&2]` (have a look again at the foo-bar example from the docs).

Comment: Thanks, @kasptom. Can you explain [&1] and [&2] in the spec. I quite don't understand it.

Comment: I've added the explanation with the relevant links.