# Jolt Transform JSON Spec for Array Input

Tags: java, jolt

I am trying to do JOLT shift operation with below spec which is not working. Not sure what mistake I have done. Need help in this case. Output JSON is coming as an object instead of Array and shift also not working as expected.

```
    Input : [
      {
        "Header": {
          "Number": 1,
          "Id": "JO"
        },
        "Name": "John"
      },
      {
        "Header": {
          "Number": 2,
          "Id": "JS"
        },
        "Name": "Justin"
      }
    ]
```

```
    Spec : [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "*": {
            "Header": "Header",
            "Name": "Header.Name"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

```
    Expected Output : [
      {
        "Header": {
          "Number": 1,
          "Id": "JO",
          "Name": "John"
        }    
      },
      {
        "Header": {
          "Number": 2,
          "Id": "JS",
          "Name": "Justin"
        }    
      }
    ]
```

```
    Actual Output : {
      "Header" : [ {
        "Number" : 1,
        "Id" : "JO",
        "Name" : "John"
      }, {
        "Number" : 2,
        "Id" : "JS"
      } ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also specify that the `"Header"` object is [inside the array](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L332).

Moreover, the index of the array where you place the `"Header"` object for each of the element of the array.

That's what the spec below does (using the `[&1]` - [apmersand wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L184) combined with array):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Header": "[&1].Header",
        "Name": "[&1].Header.Name"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

Sources:

1. [Shiftr.java javadocs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java):

   - [The arrays](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L332)
   - [The ampersand wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L184)
2. Other answer: ["How do I transform an array using Jolt?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865871/how-do-i-transform-an-array-using-jolt)
3. [Demo application](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com) linked in [the jolt repo](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) to test the spec

Comment: Thanks, @kasptom. It's working. You helped me on 3 issues till now related to JOLT.

Comment: any good source to read the documentation of jolt? this is very obscure until now...#

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I've edited the answer and added the best sources I know of.