# JOLT shift transformation to filter values in array

Tags: json, etl, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to use a JOLT transformation to do two things:

- filter the elements in the array called myarray so that only elements remain which have a "v_518" attribute
- filter out all attributes of the remaining elements except for "v_518" and "lfdn"

Input:

```
{
  "isError": false,
  "isValid": true,
  "myarray": [
    {
      "p_0001": "1",
      "p_0002": "1",
      "p_0003": "1",
      "p_0004": "1",
      "v_518": "0,214506186",
      "lfdn": 89709
    },
    {
      "p_0001": "2",
      "p_0002": "1",
      "p_0003": "1",
      "v_518": "0,3823236",
      "lfdn": 89710
    },
    {
      "p_0001": "3",
      "p_0002": "1",
      "p_0003": "1",
      "lfdn": 89711
    }
  ],
  "errorMessage": null,
  "exceptionMessage": null,
  "innerExceptionMessage": null
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "isError": false,
  "isValid": true,
  "myarray": [
    {
      "v_518": "0,214506186",
      "lfdn": 89709
    },
    {
      "v_518": "0,3823236",
      "lfdn": 89710
    }
  ],
  "errorMessage": null,
  "exceptionMessage": null,
  "innerExceptionMessage": null
}
```

What I tried so far, but doesn't work as intended:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "isError": "isError",
      "isValid": "isValid",
      "myarray": {
        // loop thru all the elements in value array
        "*": {
          "v_518": {
            // if the value "v_518" exists
            // grab the whole object and write it out to
            // a v_518_array array.
            "@(1,v_518)": "v_518_array",
            "@(1,lfdn)": "v_518_array"
          }
        }
      },
      "errorMessage": "errorMessage",
      "exceptionMessage": "exceptionMessage",
      "innerExceptionMessage": "innerExceptionMessage"
    }
  }
]
```

I tried working with the examples in http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#andrewkcarter2 but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. This answer was the hint I needed to get the ball rolling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38154541/1561441

The key is referencing the array you are currently transforming via `"value" = "array[&1].value"`.

In my mind I spent way too much time on this issue. Does anyone know of a good documentation for the Jolt syntax? I couldn't find a satisfactory one by googling myself.

```
  [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "isError": "isError",
          "isValid": "isValid",
          "myarray": {
            // loop thru all the elements in value array
            "*": {
              "v_518": {
                // if the value "v_518" exists
                // grab the whole object and write it out to
                // a v_518_array array.
                "@1": "v_518_array"
              }
            }
          },
          "errorMessage": "errorMessage",
          "exceptionMessage": "exceptionMessage",
          "innerExceptionMessage": "innerExceptionMessage"
        }
      },
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        //Transform array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865871/how-do-i-transform-an-array-using-jolt
        "spec": {
          "v_518_array": {
            // loop thru all the elements in value array
            "*": {
              "v_518": "v_518_array[&1].v_518",
              "lfdn": "v_518_array[&1].lfdn"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Here's a slightly better solution:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "isError": "isError",
      "isValid": "isValid",
      "myarray": {
        // loop thru all the elements in value array
        "*": {
          "v_518": {
            // if the value "v_518" exists
            // grab the whole object and write it out to
            // a v_518_array array.
            "@1": "v_518_array"
          }
        }
      },
      "errorMessage": "errorMessage",
      "exceptionMessage": "exceptionMessage",
      "innerExceptionMessage": "innerExceptionMessage"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    //Transform array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865871/how-do-i-transform-an-array-using-jolt
    "spec": {
      "v_518_array": {
        // loop thru all the elements in value array
        "*": {
          "v_518": "&2[&1].v_518", //notice the generic shorthand here
          "lfdn": "&2[&1].lfdn"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Still there's a briefer, and more dynamic method to figure out your issue such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "myarray": {
        "*": {
          "v_518": {
            "@(1,&)": "&3.[&2].&",
            "@(1,lfdn)": "&3.[&2].lfdn"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Very nice, I checked it and it works as well, so I gave an upvote. Do you know a good documentation of the Jolt syntax?

Comment: Hi @DRS , I frequently use [this demo](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) and believe [this source](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) would be helpful. Best wishes.