# How can I use '$' character in JOLT?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to do some data transformation using JOLT for Apache nifi but I'm running into some problem.

The sample input is:

```
{
  "id": "1234"
}
```

The sample output is:

```
{
  "$distinct_id": "1234"
}
```

My JOLT Specs:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "$distinct_id"
    }
  }
]
```

But i'm getting this error

```
Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:0.

DotNotation (write key) can not contain '*' or '$' : write key: root.$distinct_id
```

NOTE: the '$' is mandatory as it's my payload for mixpanel

Comment: `$` is soemthing special in jolt, see: [Is there a JOLT documentation? What's the meaning of the &, @ etc. operators? (NiFi, JoltTransformJSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822607/is-there-a-jolt-documentation-whats-the-meaning-of-the-etc-operators-n), so you may use this to do the transformation: `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "\\$distinct_id"
    }
  }
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to get exact JSON stated in the *sample output*, then you can use

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "\\$distinct_&" // btw, & replicates the current key "id"
    }
  }
]
```

It has a special meaning that is returning the key's value from the upper node.

This special character **$** could be escaped through use of double backslashes.