# Jolt transformation needed for multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I am trying to transform the data from a multi array to single array using jolt technique. But unable to do so. Below are the details.

Input file:

```json
{
  "oi": [
    {
      "ei": [
        {
          "type": "bs",
          "id": "797416713"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ei": [
        {
          "type": "bs",
          "id": "797416716"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt file used is as below:

```json
[
 {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "oi": {
        "*": {
          "ei": {
            "*": {
              "type": {
                "bs": {
                  "@(2,id)": "oi[#3].bs"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected output from above is as below.

```json
{
  "oi": [
    {
      "bs": [
        "797416713",
        "797416716"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual output coming from jolt is :

```json
{
  "oi": [
    {
      "bs": [
        "797416713",
        "797416716"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello @Atul Gupta and welcome to StackOverflow. I believe this answer might help you : [How do I transform an array using Jolt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865871/how-do-i-transform-an-array-using-jolt). Please format the title so it is a question (researchable, clear problem). and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may also want to add the programming language you are using in tags, along with the file format. update tags: "arrays" is unlikely to find experts for your question. Java, Json, Jolt, is better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I transform an array using Jolt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865871/how-do-i-transform-an-array-using-jolt)

Comment: Hi Atul, welcome to SO. I couldn't see a difference between the actual and the expected output. Can you please edit the expected to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the desired and actual output values are identical.
I understand from the expression

*to transform the data from a multi array to single array*

that you need to get such a result of type array of objects tagged current inner(`ei`) and outer(`oi`) keys such as(*if not please clearly state*) :

```json
[
  {
    "oi": {
      "ei": [
        {
          "type": "bs",
          "id": "797416713"
        },
        {
          "type": "bs",
          "id": "797416716"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Then, you can use this shift transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[#2].&4.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `&4` will grab the key `oi` after going 4 levels up, `&2` will grab the key `ei` after going 2 levels up the tree